# Рег. выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Вот моё рег. выражение:

```
/<a href="\/mrt\/.*" title=".*">/Usi
```

Через функцию php preg_match_all я хочу получить массив таких строк:

```
<a href="/mrt/1" title="TEST">
<a href="/mrt/2" title="TEST2">
и т.д.
```

Но почему-то моё рег. выражение не правильно работает, если в тексте встречается ссылка без title, в массив забивается большущий текст:

```
<a href="..">........<a href=".." title="">
```

В чём моя ошибка, подскажите пож-та.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/<a[^>]*href="(\/mrt\/[^"]*)"[^>]title="([^"]*)">([^<]*)<\/a>/
```

При использовании preg_match_all в $match[1] будут ссылки, в $match[2] - title'ы, в $match[3] - текст внутри ссылок (но тут не должно быть вложенных тегов).

Comment: Большое спасибо, даже и не знал об этом)) А в скобки берётся, чтобы потом сохранялось это значение в массив?

Answer (score 0):

Через "?" укажите, что title может и не быть.

Comment: Так title должен быть

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вы получаете такую строку из за использования максимальных квантификаторов... Попробуйте использовать минимальные:

`#<a href="\/mrt\/.+?" title=".+?">#Ui`

Comment: Не, это вообще фигня получается